# How to access the ID of an HTML element

Tags: jquery

How to get the value from "id" instead of from "value" and show it on the page? Now I have `Holzart:3`, I want to have `Holzart:Lärche`.

I have this function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input[name='holzart']").click(function() {        
    PobierzWartosc2();
  });
});

function PobierzWartosc2() {
  $('#aus2').html('');
  $("input[name='holzart']").each(function() {
  if (this.checked == true) {
    $('#aus2').append('Holzart:'+ $(this).val()) }
  });
}
```

and this HTML:

```
<tr><td><label>
<input type="radio" name="holzart" value="3" id="Lärche" >Lärche</label></td></tr>
```

Comment: Have you ever considered indenting your code properly? :)

Answer (score 3):

Simply use `this.id` instead of `$(this).val()`.

However, the ID is one of the worst attributes to store data unless it's the actual ID of the object. You might want to consider adding `data-something="whatever"` and then access it using `$(this).data('something')`

Answer (score 0):

So change your code. You're appending value, not ID.

```
$('#aus2').append('Holzart:'+ $(this).val()) }
    });
```

should be

```
$('#aus2').append('Holzart:'+ $(this).attr('id')) }
    });
```

**Edit**
As others recommended, it's better to use this.id instead of $(this).attr('id').

Comment: Czy Mogę użyć tej samej funkcji do przekazania małego obrazka? nie tylko wartosci tekstowej

Comment: For the benefit of others reading this thread, could you please post all future comments in English. No disrespect intended.

Comment: @Vojtas - What exactly do you mean? Are you asking about sending image path in the element's ID? Please clarify.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#aus2').append('Holzart:'+ $(this).attr('id'))
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of `$(this).val()` you need to use `$(this).attr("id")`

Answer (score 0):

Use `this.id` or `$(this).attr('id')`. The difference is that, `this` is a JavaScript object, referencing to the radio button which is clicked, but `$(this)` is a jQuery object, wrapping JavaScript object to provide more functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an improved version of your code, with annotations

```
// $(document).ready() is superfluous, use $()
$(function() {
  $("input[name='holzart']").click(function() {
    // call the function in the correct context to retain the meaning of "this"
    PobierzWartosc2.call(this);
  });
});

function PobierzWartosc2() {
  // just overwrite the current content instead of calling .html('') first
  $('#aus2').text( this.checked ? this.id : '' );
}
```

basically, you want:

```
$(function() {
  $(":radio[name='holzart']").click(function() {
    $('#aus2').text( this.checked ? this.id : '' );
  });
});
```

Other than that, I agree with [ThiefMaster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6624259/how-to-access-the-id-of-an-html-element/6624276#6624276) that `id` is terrible place to store any kind of data.

Use HTML5 `data-*` attributes or store additional data - or a hidden `<span>` for example (if your page is not HTML5). In your case you cold even simply use the text of the associated `<label>`:

```
$(function() {
  $(":radio[name='holzart']").click(function() {
    var $label = $("label[for='" + this.id + "']");
    $('#aus2').text( this.checked ? $label.text() : '' );
  });
});
```